# Facebook profile URL

Tags: facebook

My Facebook profile link is in the form https://facebook.com/john.smith where John Smith is my display name. The email however which I use to log in is jsmith@email.com

My mom's Facebook profile page is https://facebook.com/maryp while her display name is Mary Poppins, while the email she uses to log in is maryp@email.com

Furthermore, I have friend, when I went to his profile page, address was https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100000077777777

How come Facebook uses different ways to form profile URL? Firstly, user public name, secondly, user email (which is not secure at all), and thirdly, user id? Where this can be changed?

Answer (score -1):

You can follow the link below. Hope it helps!
https://www.wikihow.com/Change-Your-Facebook-URL